# Problem in reading password using ansible prompt

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a code as follows, it asks the user to enter a password.

```
---
- name: read password
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
   - name: admin_password
     prompt: "enter password for admin"
  tasks:
   - name: echo password to a file
     shell: echo {{admin_password}} >> /root/admin_password
```

I have entered the password: **cPUtnZjn$s2O**
but got only **cPUtnZjn** in /root/admin_password

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell on the remote computer interprets the $s2O part of your password as variable (which is empty, so no output for that part).

Use single inverted comma to bracket your output string:

```
     shell: echo '{{admin_password}}' >> /root/admin_password
```